# Check whether a sequence belongs to an open ball

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How to check if the sequence x=( 
    x1
  , x2
  ,...) where  
    xn
  =1-(1/n) belongs to the open ball B(0,1) in the normed space l^∞ of all bounded sequences with the norm defined by ‖y‖=sup{|yn|: n∈N}

Comment: Well, what is the norm of $x$? Is it less than $1$?

Comment: @DavidMitra of course

Comment: @DavidMitra do you mean that the answer is true ?

Comment: $\Vert x\Vert=\sup_n\{0,1/2,2/3,4/5,\ldots, 1-1/n,\ldots \}=1$. So, $x\notin B(0,1)$.

Comment: you are right . I forgot that it's an open ball. can you post you answer so I can mark it as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can compute the norm of $x$ and find it has value $1$. As $B(0,1)=\{\, y\in\ell_\infty \mid\Vert y\Vert<1\,\}$, $x\notin B(0,1)$.